Dynamically pass ID value in URL of API in Azure Data Factory
I can query this api call (a dummy url): https://something.com/actions to produce the following records: 
I can also query the API call: https://something.com/actions/{id}/analysis-code-values by dynamically passing each ActionID as part of the URL: 
I can achieve this logic on Power BI, however I want to replicate it on Azure Data Factory using a copy data activity to take source data from Rest API and sink into an Azure SQL Database.
Here is what I have done so far:
Linked Service:  
For each activity: 
The data from the api call, https://something.com/actions, looks like
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1001,
        "lastModified": "2020-07-21T12:46:54.124802Z",
        "active": true,
        "projectId": 3,
        "issue": "Please implement this control in accordance with the Timeline specified and reach out to the CCI Compliance Team if you need any guidance ",
        "recommendation": "",
        "detail": "Please implement this control in accordance with the Timeline specified and reach out to the CCI Compliance Team if you need any guidance ",
        "managementAction": "",
        "ownerId": 91,
        "assigneeId": 497,
        "groupId": null,
        "fixedTarget": "2019-09-30T00:00:00Z",
        "variableTarget": "2019-09-30T00:00:00Z",
        "variableDeadline": null,
        "closed": "2019-09-02T22:03:31.88Z",
        "status": 4,
        "timing": 0,
        "progress": 0,
        "hasBudget": true,
        "budgetTotal": 0,
        "actionCost": 0,
        "additionalFinancial": null,
        "additionalTextSingle": "",
        "additionalTextMultiple": "",
        "additionalDate": null,
        "opened": null,
        "supressAlerts": false,
        "links": {
            "project": "/api/client/v1.6/projects/3",
            "owner": "/api/client/v1.6/users/91",
            "assignee": "/api/client/v1.6/users/497"
        }
    }

Using action ID of 1001 as an example, the data for the api call
https://something.com/actions/1001/analysis-code-values looks like:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 89,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 7,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/7",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/7/values/89"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 94,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 18,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/18",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/18/values/94"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 180,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 14,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/14",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/14/values/180"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 223,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 12,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/12",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/12/values/223"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 306,
      "lastModified": "2024-01-14T18:00:22.289601Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 10,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/10",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/10/values/306"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 317,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 9,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/9",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/9/values/317"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 332,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 16,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/16",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/16/values/332"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 357,
      "lastModified": "2023-12-12T19:08:15.2611576Z",
      "analysisCodeId": 20,
      "links": {
        "analysis code": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/20",
        "analysis code value": "/api/client/v1.6/analysis-codes/20/values/357"
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": null
}

Using Pratiks logic on Action ID 1001 and 1002, I'm able to successfully pass those action IDs in the URL however it's not appending them to the table like in my Power BI send screenshot. What I need is a column to say Action ID and then the columns listed below

The desired top row should look like:
Action ID, id, lastmodified, analysiscodeid
How would I use the above to append the action ID's and replicate the logic I achieved on Power BI?

This approach looks correct. Are you facing any error?

can you add from where you are getting actin Id?

That's the part I'm stuck on, any help with screenshots if possible would be much appreciated
